# JavaScript - Need a way to set OuterHeight of the Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an container element which is sort of a layout container for its children and based on some attributes I have to arrange children.

I need simple way to set outerHeight of an element, something like,

```
$(e).setOuterHeight(200);
```

jQuery's outerHeight does not set the height at all, indeed its a readonly method.

```
$(e).height(200); // this clips my element
```

In above method, I loose borders of input of type text.

My element's children are docked based on available space and some other criteria based on data that it holds, simple layouts like float,clear etc will not work because padding etc change dynamically based on sizes. I will finally end up using Table, even if I dont want to but have no choice, but anyway thanks for the help.

Now when element is sized to more then children then there is no problem, but sometimes container element may have lesser height then the children and that time, I need to increase the size.

```
function calculateSize(e){
   var s = { 
      width: $(e).innerWidth(), 
      height: 0 
   };
   var ae = new Enumerator(e.children);
   while(ae.next()){
      var child = ae.current();
      // I have tried all alternatives
      // for following lines
      // child.clientHeight || child.offsetHeight
      // $(child).outerHeight()
      // $(child).innerHeight()
      s.height += $(child).outerHeight(); 
   }
   if(s.height > $(e).height()){
      $(e).height(s.height);
   }
}

function layoutChildren(e){
      ....
      /// for every child c
      /// some steps before
      var heightForChildren = 
        calculatedWithPadMarginBorder(availableHeight,c);
      /// tried combinations
      $(c).height(heightForChildren);
      /// last statement fails for button
      /// as button's padding cuts itself
      /// removing padding in calculation
      /// cuts other input elements !!
      /// some steps after
      ....
}
```

I need some explanation of how to calculate runtime height/width including/excluding padding/margin/border etc and how to set it correctly so that I dont run into problems. I cant keep on trying all permutations combinations as I dont see a correct documentation even on jQuery website.

Fixed height calculations are fine, but this is kind of a dynamic element which resizes itself and arranges children in specific order.

Problem is there is no way to set outerHeight, when we set height/width of an element, the height/width is actually inner height/width without taking margin into consideration, while when we want to resize parent, we need outerHeight, but we cannot set back the outerHeight that easily.

My calculateSize and layoutChildren are two separate methods and two separate algorithms because parent will be resized to sum of all children's height. And then height is simply divided by no. of children stacked one above other. My calculation is perfect, but in my layoutChildren method I have "outerHeight" and "outerWidth" of element and have no idea on how to set it correctly by using jQuery or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is strange but this is the Answer.

There are weird controls,

- SELECT
- BUTTON (INPUT[type=submit|reset|button])

WebKit Browsers

- Padding and Border are considered as part of OuterWidth for all controls
- Padding and Border must be added to Width as OuterWidth for all controls
- Padding and Border are considered as part of InnerWidth for "weird controls"
- Padding and Border must be subtracted from Width before setting the Width for all "non weird controls"

Non WebKit Browsers

- Padding and Border are considered as part of OuterWidth for all non "weird controls"
- Padding and Border must be added to Width as OuterWidth for all non "weird controls"
- Padding and Border are considered as part of InnerWidth for all non "weird controls"
- Padding and Border must be subtracted from Width before setting the Width for all "non weird controls"

Answer (score 5):

`.outerHeight( value )`
`version added: 1.8.0`

you can use `jQuery.outerHeight(value)` to set the value of an element's outer height. Ex: `$foo.outerHeight( 200 )`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a special requirement, a standard  element by default sizes its height to match its children.  If you style the  to float:left or float:right its default width will then also be that to contain all its children.

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy to help, but I simply do not understand your question.
In regards to the documentation of the dimensions methods of jQuery I found that http://api.jquery.com/category/css/ holds documentation on both innerWidth(), innerHeight(), outerWidth() and outerHeight().

I hope this helps, otherwise, try reading through your question, making it more obvious what you need the answer for.

Comment: I want to set outerHeight to the element, jQuery gives me the outerHeight, but how do I set it to the element?

Comment: Okay, now I understand. This is a basic problem with the CSS boxmodel: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html which have been heavily debated.
I suggest a rather ugly approach, since we are already dealing with javascript calculations of heights. This is you calculate the difference in outerHeight, with and without margins, and when you set the height you add this difference.
I hope this makes sense - though I would highly recommend that you try to find a CSS solution for this, in general these types of arrangement of elements issues always have a CSS solution that runs smoother than a JS solution

Comment: :) that is really an ugly solution, and unfortunately calculations still do not perform well, because I have just found out, SELECT and BUTTON are the only controls that has different calculation then other controls and only those ones are clipped. I would love CSS solution but once again we are dealing with 30% of IE users, and IE 7-8 still works weird with CSS2.

Comment: Shouldn't be your problem ... IE will die with the lack of developer attention (though this is just my humble hope - and I know this is not supposed to be a discussion board)